# What is the ClojureScript equivalent of a JavaScript scope taking an argument

Tags: closures, clojurescript

I want to write a program which adds complex behavior to a div (think some kind of interactive graphic, for example). I would like to be able to pass a div to a function in the library and have the library add behavior to the div.

If I were doing this in JavaScript, I would write the following.

In `my_page.html`:

```
<div id="program-container"></div>

<script src="my_library.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    useDivForACoolProgram(document.getElementById("program-container"));
</script>
```

In `my_library.js`:

```
function useDivForACoolProgram(div) {
    var x = 2;
    var y = 3;

    function setup() {
        div.innerHTML = "Getting ready to run...";
        doMainSetup();
    }

    function doMainSetup() {
        ...

    // Lots more functions, many of which refer to div
}
```

Note that the library exposes a single function which accepts a div. When we pass it a div, the library keeps all of its state in a closure associated with the passed div, which would potentially allow me to add this behavior to many divs on the page if I were so inclined.

I want to do the same sort of thing in ClojureScript. My first attempt was as follows:

```
(defn use-div-for-a-cool-program [div]
    (def x 2)
    (def y 3)

    (defn setup []
        (set! (.innerHTML div) "Getting ready to run...")
        (do-main-setup))

    (defn do-main-setup []
        ...

    ;; Lots more functions, many of which refer to div
)
```

But this doesn't work, because `def` and `defn` define variables at the module's scope rather than defining variables local to `use-div-for-a-cool-program`. If I were to call `use-div-for-a-cool-program` multiple times with different divs, all of the new `def`s and `defn`s would override the old each time.

One solution would be to use `let` instead, but this is a bit unsatisfying because it forces us to give the implementation of functions before they can be referenced and is also hard to read, e.g.

```
(defn use-div-for-a-cool-program [div]
    (let [x 2
          y 3
          do-main-setup (fn []
                            ...)
          setup (fn []
                    (set! (.innerHTML div) "Getting ready to run...")
                    (do-main-setup))
          ;; Lots more functions, many of which refer to div
         ]
      (setup)))
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is not what you want to hear :) You pass `div` as an argument to each function. Instead of coupling the functions to `div` implicitly you specify explicitly that a div is needed:

```clj
(defn do-main-setup [div]
  ...)

(defn setup [div]
  (set! (.innerHTML div) "Getting ready to run...")

(defn use-div-for-a-cool-program [div]
    (let [x 2
          y 3]
      (do-main-setup div))
      ;; Lots more functions, many of which refer to div explicitly
      (setup div)))
```

Even if this is a little bit more verbose (as you pass `div` every time) it makes your intent clear. I use a closure when I want to return the function and call it later, remembering the scope in which it was defined. I don't see how it helps to define those functions as closures and call them precisely after.

If you want to keep some state associated to your `div` I would also do so explicitly. For example, if you want to keep count of how many clicks your div received I would do this:

```clj
(defn add-state-handler [div state]
  (set! (.onclick div) #(swap! state inc)))

(defn use-div-for-a-cool-program [div]
    (let [x 2
          y 3
          counter (atom 0)]
      (do-main-setup div))
      (add-state-handler div counter)
      ;; Other functions that reference div and counter
      (setup div)))
```

In short, I would avoid handling any state or mutable values (`counter` or `div`) implicitly. If you have to render a view that depends on some changing state I would recommend any Clojurescript React wrapper like [Om](https://github.com/swannodette/om) or [Reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent).

Comment: I like what you're trying to do here, but suppose that my program carries state with it. As a simple example, suppose I want to keep track of how many times the div has been clicked. If I were doing this with closures, I would keep a mutable variable in the closure so all of my functions could reference it and each div would automatically get its own variable. Where would you keep this state in your example?